# For Liquibase createView, is there a way to store a value of a subsearch?

Tags: sql, sql-server, liquibase, liquibase-sql

I am trying to create a view in SQL Server using a liquiBase yaml changelog file where each row looks like:

```
employee_id | provider_id | days_remaining | employed_dates
```

and there are three tables

- EMPLOYEE - employee_id, first_name, last_name
- JOB - job_id, employee_id, start_date, end_date, provider_id
- ASSIGNMENT - assignment_id, job_id, employee_id, start_date, end_date, provider_id
- `employee_id` given for the row
- `provider_id` is the `provider_id` of the `job_id` that has the latest `end_date` for this `employee_id`
- `days_remaining` is the number of days left until the last assignment end day for this `employee_id` for the above `provider_id`
- `employed_dates` is a concatenation of all of the `assignment_id` for this `employee_id` for the above `provider_id`

My code so far:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
  id: 100
  author: 100
  dbms: "mssql"
  changes:
    - createView:
        schemaName: ${schemaName}
        viewName: employee_history_view
        replaceIfExists: true
        selectQuery: >
          SELECT EMPLOYEE.employee_id,
          (
            SELECT TOP 1 provider_id from JOB
            where JOB.employee_id = employee_id
            order by end_date DESC
          ) as provider_id,
          employee.first_name,
          employee.last_name,
          DATEDIFF(DAY,
          (
            SELECT max(ASSIGNMENT.end_Date)
            from ASSIGNMENT
            where ASSIGNMENT.employee_id = EMPLOYEE.employee_id
            and ASSIGNMENT.provider_id = (
                                            SELECT TOP 1 provider_id from JOB
                                            where JOB.employee_id = employee_id
                                            order by end_date DESC
                                          )
            and end_date < getDate()
          ),
          getdate() ) as days_remaining,
          (
            '[' + SUBSTRING (
              (
                SELECT TOP 100 ', {"start":"'+CONVERT(CHAR(10),ASSIGNMENT.start_date,120)+'","end":"'+CONVERT(CHAR(10),ASSIGNMENT.end_date,120)+'"}'
                from ASSIGNMENT
                where ASSIGNMENT.employee_id = EMPLOYEE.employee_id
                and ASSIGNMENT.provider_id = (
                                                SELECT TOP 1 provider_id from JOB
                                                where JOB.employee_id = EMPLOYEE.employee_id
                                                order by end_date DESC
                                              )
                order by program_type DESC
                for xml path ('')
              ), 2, 8000) + ']'
          ) as employed_dates
          FROM ${employeeSchema}.EMPLOYEE
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to avoid redundantly calculating provider_id (the below code) three times?

   ```
   SELECT TOP 1 provider_id 
   FROM JOB  
   WHERE JOB.employee_id = employee_id  
   ORDER BY end_date DESC
   ```

   Since there are no support for variables, variable tables, or CTEs in liquibase, how else could I do this?
2. Is it possible to modify the above so that each employee_id is listed in multiple rows (for each provider_id associated to this employee_id)? UNIONs won't work because liquibase does not support loops or some kind of for-each construct, and CROSS JOINS won't work as it would pair employee_ids to every provider_id whether or not they are associated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, wasn't thinking clearly before, this could be solved with just the following INNER JOIN at the end:

```
          INNER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT employee_id, provider_id from JOB
          ) as DT
          ON EMPLOYEE.employee_id = DT.employee_id
```